# Woocommerce short description keep html tags

Tags: html, woocommerce

I am trying to display the product short description on my front page. My problem is, that the html-tags, for example lists, are not displayed. The text comes without any html. On my single-product page everything is displayed fine.
Is there a way to keep these tags?

I use this code:

get_short_description(); ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the short description in wordpress, `the_excerpt()` function works perfectly!

try this:

```
<?php echo the_excerpt() ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, its really perfect :)